# Rendering of react components in unexpected way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I am trying to create a simple todolist using store2.js library. There is a problem in rendering the elements in that to do list.

```
  var React = require('react');
var store = require("store2");
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
class CreateToDoList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.inputVal="";
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
        this.addValueToList = this.addValueToList.bind(this);
        this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);
  };
  handleInput(e)
   {
     this.inputValue=e.target.value;
   }
addValueToList(){
  if(store.has("todoList")===false)
  {
    store.set("todoList",{count:0})
  }
  var count=store.get("todoList").count;
  count+=1;
  var obj={
      value:this.inputValue,
      isChecked:false
    };
  store.transact("todoList",function(elements){
      elements[count+""]=obj;
      elements.count=count
  });console.log(store.getAll("todoList"));debugger;
  }
  render() {
    return ( <div>
      <input type="input" onChange={this.handleInput}/>
       <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.addValueToList}>Add</Button>
      <CreateShowPreviousTasks/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class todoValues  extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(){
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.props)
      return(
      <div >
          <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.isCheck}></input>
          <input type="input">{this.prop.value}</input>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class CreateShowPreviousTasks extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("here")
  }
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(event)
  {
  }
  render() {
    if (store.has('todoList') !== undefined) {
      var divElements=[];
      this.loop=0;
      var count=store.get("todoList").count;
      for(this.loop=0;this.loop<count;this.loop++)
      {
        var obj=store.get("todoList");
        obj=obj[count+""];
        divElements.push(
         <todoValues value={obj.value} key={this.loop+1}/>
        )
      }
    } else {
      store.set('todoList',{
        count:0
      })
    }
    return (<div>{divElements}</div>
    )
  }
}
export default CreateToDoList;
```

The class `todoValues` adds the div elements of two input buttons wrapped in a div. But the rendering is only done as `<todovalues value="as"></todovalues>`.
The class `CreateShowPreviousTasks` which retrieves the list of stored items in the local storage items and passing those values as properties to `todoValues` and wrapping as in a div.

Answer (score 0):

use the folliwng syntax to render a list

```
render() {
    let todos = store.get("todolist");

    return (
    <div>
    {
        Object.keys(todos).map(function(key){
            let todo = todos[key];
            return (<todoValues value={ todo.value } key={ key }/>)
        })
    }
    </div>
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: What's the error ? what it the structure of the store.get("todolist") variable ?

Comment: I've edited my comment, a ) was placed at the wrong place